# JSF Validator and outputLabel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm working with a web application with the following technologies
spring 4.3
JSF 2.2.14
PrimeFaces 6.1
Omnifaces 2.6.4

I need to validate an h:inputText, and I'm trying to use the javax.faces.validator.Validator interface.

All is working well but when the validation fail, I'm not able to retrieve the label of the field, that is stored in a p:outputLabel using the "for" attribute.

Facelets code

```
<p:outputLabel id="selectedAdvPriceOutputLabel" for="selectedAdvPrice" value="#{msg['prezzo']}"/>

<h:inputText id="selectedAdvPrice" 
             value="#{addAdvertisingController.advertisingBean.price}" 
             class="form-control" 
             converter="javax.faces.BigDecimal" 
             required="#{empty param[draftSave.clientId] and empty param[draftSaveXS.clientId]}" 
             requiredMessage="#{msg['prezzo']} #{msg['campoObbligatorio']}">
  <f:validator binding="#{numberGreaterThanZeroJsfValidator}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Validator - validate method

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            String v = value.toString();
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(v)) {
                try {
                    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(v);
                    if(bd.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0){
                        // how to retrieve the field label???
                        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("messageWithout label", "messageWithout label");
                        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                        throw new ValidatorException(msg, new IllegalArgumentException(exceptionMessage));
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("messageWithout label", "messageWithout label");
                        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                        throw new ValidatorException(msg, new IllegalArgumentException(exceptionMessage));
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

How can I retrieve the value attribute of the p:outputLabel linked to the h:inputText that is not passing the validation?
Thank you

Comment: Does it work for an `h:outputlabel` ?

Comment: Do you need to use `h:inputText` instead of `p:inputText` ?

Comment: The problem is the same because the label attribute for the <h:inputText is null and I don't know how to retrieve the *:outputLabel linked to him

Comment: If you want to use the value causing the error you could use a <h:message /> tag instead. This component renders all Errormessages and you just would need to add the message text by throwing a validation exception as you already do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Primefaces User's Guide --> 3.93 OutputLabel](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf)

> **Auto Label** 
>   OutputLabel sets its value as the label of the target component to be displayed in validation errors so the target component
>   does not need to define the label attribute again.
>
> ```
> <h:outputLabel for="input" value="Field" />
> <p:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.text}" label="Field"/>
> ```
>
> can be rewritten as;
>
> ```
> <p:outputLabel for="input" value="Field" />
> <p:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.text}" />
> ```

It means, that `OutputLabel` simply sets the `label` attributte of a component   to which the label is attached.

Just retrieve this attributte in the validator, for example in this way:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

    Object labelObj = component.getAttributes().get("label");
    String label = (labelObj!=null) ? labelObj.toString() : "Unknown label";
    .....
    .....
    // how to retrieve the field label???
    String message = String.format("%s : My conversion error message", label);
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(message,message) ;
    .....
    .....
```

I've tested it and it works for both `p:inputText` and `h:inputText` components.

---

> Hi, I've debugged the code and component.getAttributes().get("label")
>   is null

I've tested it again on JSF 2.2/Primefaces 6.1/Wildfy 10.x and it works.
Here is a simple demo project on [GitHub link](https://github.com/kordirko/jsf_outputlabel)

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panel id="panel" header="Form" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <p:messages id="messages" />

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

                <p:outputLabel id="label1_id"
                    for="input1_id" value="This Is My label for h:input" />

                <h:inputText id="input1_id" value="#{myBean.price1}"
                    required="true" >
                    <f:validator validatorId="MyValidator" />
                </h:inputText>

                <p:outputLabel id="label2_id"
                    for="input2_id" value="This Is My label for p:input" />

                <p:inputText id="input2_id" value="#{myBean.price2}" required="true">
                    <f:validator validatorId="MyValidator" />
                </p:inputText>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton update="panel" value="Submit" />

        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**bean**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5455916691447931918L;

    private Integer price1;

    private Integer price2;

    public Integer getPrice2() {
        return price2;
    }

    public void setPrice2(Integer price2) {
        this.price2 = price2;
    }

    public Integer getPrice1() {
        return price1;
    }

    public void setPrice1(Integer price1) {
        this.price1 = price1;
    }
}
```

**Validator**

```
@FacesValidator("MyValidator")
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

        Object labelObj = component.getAttributes().get("label");
        String label = (labelObj!=null) ? labelObj.toString() : "Unknown label";

        if (value != null) {
            String v = value.toString();
            if (null != v && !v.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(v);
                    if (bd.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0) {
                        // how to retrieve the field label???
                        String message = String.format("%s : Value must be greater than 0", label);
                        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(message,message) ;
                        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                        throw new ValidatorException(msg, new IllegalArgumentException("Validator exception:" + message));
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    String message = String.format("%s : Value must be a number", label);
                    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(message,message);
                    msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                    throw new ValidatorException(msg, new IllegalArgumentException("Validator exception:" + message));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

And a result is:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I've debugged the code and component.getAttributes().get("label") is null even if I've tried to switch from h:inputText to p:inputText. The only attributes I've are "com.sun.faces.facelets.MARK_ID" and "javax.faces.component.VIEW_LOCATION_KEY"

Comment: @Gavi I've tested it again, it works. I've appended my example project to the answer.

Comment: For some reason when I inspect "component.getAttributes()" show me only two keys that I've told you. But if I try to execute "component.getAttributes().get("label")" is working. I've found the same code inside the javax.faces.validator.MessageFactory class. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some things that may help or are common:

- remove `id` from `*:outputLabel` as this is not needed
- use `validatorMessage="#{bundle.SOME_FIELD_VALIDATION_ERROR}"` to have a localizable message, if your validator is throwing `javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException` (you can import this above your validator class, of course)
- get rid of the code for the label-retrieval, see above `validatorMessage` field
- `<f:validator binding="#{someValidator}" />` seem to cause more problems, common way is: `<f:validator validatorId="SomeFooValidator" />` within `*:inputText` (you have to make it non-self-closing)
- and then annotate your validator class with `@FacesValidator ("SomeFooValidator")` (`javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator`)

Are you using JSF2.2?